# .NET MAUI - Azure Speech Service

Tags: .net, xamarin, .net-maui

I am trying to integrate my .NET MAUI app with Azure cognitive speech service, following the old xamarin tutorial from microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-cognitive-services/speech-recognition

According to this guy [MAUI-Android: How to keep Google Speech Recognizer from timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951297/maui-android-how-to-keep-google-speech-recognizer-from-timeout) it should work.

The implementation part of the microphone service is giving me compilation errors. This is the code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Google.Android.Material.Snackbar;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Atk.Progen.NETMAUI.Interfaces;
using Atk.Progen.NETMAUI.Platforms.Android;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android;

namespace Atk.Progen.NETMAUI.Platforms.Android
{
    public class MicrophoneService
{
    public const int RecordAudioPermissionCode = 1;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsPermissions;
    string[] permissions = new string[] { Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio };

    public MicrophoneService()
    {
        tcsPermissions = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    }

    public Task<bool> GetPermissionAsync()
    {

        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23)
        {
            tcsPermissions.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            var currentActivity = MainActivity.Instance;
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(currentActivity, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestMicPermissions();
            }
            else
            {
                tcsPermissions.TrySetResult(true);
            }

        }

        return tcsPermissions.Task;
    }

    public void OnRequestPermissionResult(bool isGranted)
    {
        tcsPermissions.TrySetResult(isGranted);
    }

    void RequestMicPermissions()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.Instance, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio))
        {
            Snackbar.Make(MainActivity.Instance.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content),
                    "Microphone permissions are required for speech transcription!",
                    Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                    .SetAction("Ok", v =>
                    {
                        ((Activity)MainActivity.Instance).RequestPermissions(permissions, RecordAudioPermissionCode);
                    })
                    .Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions((Activity)MainActivity.Instance, permissions, RecordAudioPermissionCode);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The error is on MainActivity.Istance and on Android.Resource.Id.Content.
It says "MainActivity does not contain definition for Instance".

Any suggestion on how to make it work on .net MAUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android support for MAUI has been released in Speech SDK 1.24.0 release. You should be able to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech in your MAUI app for Android.

Additionally, we will be releasing support for iOS and Maccatalyst in 1.25.0 release ETA Jan 2023.